# Событие click и submit формы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ситуация такая.
В форме есть некоторое кол-во *input*, так же в форме есть элементы (картинки и прочее) на которых висят события клик. 
Находясь в *input* жмем enter и почему-то вызывается клик на стороннем элементе формы. В чем может быть причина?

Срабатывает клик на элементе `.cart_item_delete` Код js ниже - единственный во всем js файле, который связан с классом `.cart_item_delete`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.cart_item_delete', function() {
  if ($(this).find('.wrapper_answer').hasClass('show_answer')) {
    $(this).find('.wrapper_answer').removeClass('show_answer');
  } else {
    $(this).find('.wrapper_answer').addClass('show_answer');
  }

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form c lass="cart_form" method="post">
  <div class="item_line_nomargin"></div>
  <div class="cart_left_wrap">
    <div class="cart_border">
      <div class="cart_item_photo">
        <a href="/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v">
          <img alt="LED Телевизор LG 43UF670V" src="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="cart_item_text">
        <div class="cart_item_name"><a href="/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v">LED Телевизор LG 43UF670V</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item_avb availability_yes">В наличии</div>
        <div class="cart_item_quantity_wrap clearfix">
          <a href="cart/view?id=425913" onclick="return cart.view(425913,'/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v')" class="view-product">Посмотреть товар</a>
          <div class="cart_item_quantity">
            <a href="/cart?pc[0-388599]=1" class="quantity-cart-minus" onclick="return cart.quantity('0-388599',-1)"><span class="quantity-cart-minus"></span></a> 
            <input type="text" name="pc[0-388599]" value="2" class="quantity" onclick="this.select()"> <a href="/cart?pc[0-388599]=3" class="quantity-cart-plus" onclick="return cart.quantity('0-388599',1)"><span class="quantity-cart-plus"></span></a> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cart_item_price_wrap">
        <a href="?del[0-388599]=1" class="cart_item_delete">
          <div class="wrapper_answer">
            <div class="answer">
              <p class="answer_text"><span>Вы уверены, что хотите удалить товар<br> из корзины?</span>
              </p>
              <div class="answer_buttons">
                <button class="del_from_cart answer_button_left" value="no">Нет</button>
                <button class="del_from_cart answer_button_right" value="yes" onclick="return cart._delete('0-388599')">Да</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="product-code">Код: id425913</div>
        <s style="visibility: hidden">&nbsp;</s>  <strong>
       <span class="span_word">Цена:</span>
       <span class="span_price">34&nbsp;157<span class="tRub">руб</span></span>
       </strong>
        <br>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return cart.toggle('0-388599')" title="Выбрать данный тип оплаты">
       Цена в кредит: от <span>1&nbsp;982<span class="tRub">руб</span>/мес</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!--cart_border-->
    <div id="promo-code">
      <div>
        <label title="Введите промо-код">
          <span>Введите промо-код</span>
          <input id="promo-code-value" maxlength="19" placeholder="Введите промо-код" type="text">
        </label>
        <button id="promo-code-apply" role="button" type="submit">Применить</button>
      </div>
      <span id="promo-code-message"></span>
    </div>

  </div>lass="cart_form" method="post">
  <div class="item_line_nomargin"></div>
  <div class="cart_left_wrap">
    <div class="cart_border">
      <div class="cart_item_photo">
        <a href="/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v">
          <img alt="LED Телевизор LG 43UF670V" src="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="cart_item_text">
        <div class="cart_item_name"><a href="/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v">LED Телевизор LG 43UF670V</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item_avb availability_yes">В наличии</div>
        <div class="cart_item_quantity_wrap clearfix">
          <a href="cart/view?id=425913" onclick="return cart.view(425913,'/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v')" class="view-product">Посмотреть товар</a>
          <div class="cart_item_quantity">
            <a href="/cart?pc[0-388599]=1" class="quantity-cart-minus" onclick="return cart.quantity('0-388599',-1)"><span class="quantity-cart-minus"></span></a> 
            <input type="text" name="pc[0-388599]" value="2" class="quantity" onclick="this.select()"> <a href="/cart?pc[0-388599]=3" class="quantity-cart-plus" onclick="return cart.quantity('0-388599',1)"><span class="quantity-cart-plus"></span></a> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cart_item_price_wrap">
        <a href="?del[0-388599]=1" class="cart_item_delete">
          <div class="wrapper_answer">
            <div class="answer">
              <p class="answer_text"><span>Вы уверены, что хотите удалить товар<br> из корзины?</span>
              </p>
              <div class="answer_buttons">
                <button class="del_from_cart answer_button_left" value="no">Нет</button>
                <button class="del_from_cart answer_button_right" value="yes" onclick="return cart._delete('0-388599')">Да</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="product-code">Код: id425913</div>
        <s style="visibility: hidden">&nbsp;</s>  <strong>
       <span class="span_word">Цена:</span>
       <span class="span_price">34&nbsp;157<span class="tRub">руб</span></span>
       </strong>
        <br>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return cart.toggle('0-388599')" title="Выбрать данный тип оплаты">
       Цена в кредит: от <span>1&nbsp;982<span class="tRub">руб</span>/мес</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!--cart_border-->
    <div id="promo-code">
      <div>
        <label title="Введите промо-код">
          <span>Введите промо-код</span>
          <input id="promo-code-value" maxlength="19" placeholder="Введите промо-код" type="text">
        </label>
        <button id="promo-code-apply" role="button" type="button">Применить</button>
      </div>
      <span id="promo-code-message"></span>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

[Пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=wIV14SDh3x)

Comment: Есть у вас в form есть submit, то производиться клик на него. Нужно с помощью скрипта назначить, что бы когда "вошёл" в input, клик не производился

Comment: как раз таки клик не производится на тайп сабмит , вызывается клик на иконке подсказки в моей форме

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, код формы в вопрос. Тогда пользователи сайта быстрее вам ответят

Comment: в форме очень много html кода

Comment: Загрузите форму на https://jsfiddle.net/ и загрузите ссылку сюда

Comment: @Yuri не давайте плохих советов, на [ru.so] есть встроенный сниппет.

Comment: @amijin напишите в вопросе минимальный воспроизводимый пример проблемы (не забудьте указать проблемный код jquery/javascript).

Comment: Есть какие-то идеи?

Comment: @amijin, сейчас пораскинем мозгами. Кто-то всё равно придумает

Comment: Это норма размещать в форме такой жирный код ?:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас не указан тип кнопок, т.е. сделайте:

```
<button class="del_from_cart answer_button_left" type="button" value="no">Нет</button>
<button class="del_from_cart answer_button_right" type="button" value="yes" onclick="return cart._delete('0-388599')">Да</button>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.cart_item_delete', function() {
  console.log('test click'); //для теста
  if ($(this).find('.wrapper_answer').hasClass('show_answer')) {
    $(this).find('.wrapper_answer').removeClass('show_answer');
  } else {
    $(this).find('.wrapper_answer').addClass('show_answer');
  }

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form c lass="cart_form" method="post">
  <div class="item_line_nomargin"></div>
  <div class="cart_left_wrap">
    <div class="cart_border">
      <div class="cart_item_photo">
        <a href="/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v">
          <img alt="LED Телевизор LG 43UF670V" src="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="cart_item_text">
        <div class="cart_item_name"><a href="/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v">LED Телевизор LG 43UF670V</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item_avb availability_yes">В наличии</div>
        <div class="cart_item_quantity_wrap clearfix">
          <a href="cart/view?id=425913" onclick="return cart.view(425913,'/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v')" class="view-product">Посмотреть товар</a>
          <div class="cart_item_quantity">
            <a href="/cart?pc[0-388599]=1" class="quantity-cart-minus" onclick="return cart.quantity('0-388599',-1)"><span class="quantity-cart-minus"></span></a> 
            <input type="text" name="pc[0-388599]" value="2" class="quantity" onclick="this.select()"> <a href="/cart?pc[0-388599]=3" class="quantity-cart-plus" onclick="return cart.quantity('0-388599',1)"><span class="quantity-cart-plus"></span></a> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cart_item_price_wrap">
        <a href="?del[0-388599]=1" class="cart_item_delete">
          <div class="wrapper_answer">
            <div class="answer">
              <p class="answer_text"><span>Вы уверены, что хотите удалить товар<br> из корзины?</span>
              </p>
              <div class="answer_buttons">
                <button class="del_from_cart answer_button_left" type="button" value="no">Нет</button>
                <button class="del_from_cart answer_button_right" type="button" value="yes" onclick="return cart._delete('0-388599')">Да</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="product-code">Код: id425913</div>
        <s style="visibility: hidden">&nbsp;</s>  <strong>
       <span class="span_word">Цена:</span>
       <span class="span_price">34&nbsp;157<span class="tRub">руб</span></span>
       </strong>
        <br>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return cart.toggle('0-388599')" title="Выбрать данный тип оплаты">
       Цена в кредит: от <span>1&nbsp;982<span class="tRub">руб</span>/мес</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!--cart_border-->
    <div id="promo-code">
      <div>
        <label title="Введите промо-код">
          <span>Введите промо-код</span>
          <input id="promo-code-value" maxlength="19" placeholder="Введите промо-код" type="text">
        </label>
        <button id="promo-code-apply" role="button" type="submit">Применить</button>
      </div>
      <span id="promo-code-message"></span>
    </div>

  </div>lass="cart_form" method="post">
  <div class="item_line_nomargin"></div>
  <div class="cart_left_wrap">
    <div class="cart_border">
      <div class="cart_item_photo">
        <a href="/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v">
          <img alt="LED Телевизор LG 43UF670V" src="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="cart_item_text">
        <div class="cart_item_name"><a href="/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v">LED Телевизор LG 43UF670V</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item_avb availability_yes">В наличии</div>
        <div class="cart_item_quantity_wrap clearfix">
          <a href="cart/view?id=425913" onclick="return cart.view(425913,'/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v')" class="view-product">Посмотреть товар</a>
          <div class="cart_item_quantity">
            <a href="/cart?pc[0-388599]=1" class="quantity-cart-minus" onclick="return cart.quantity('0-388599',-1)"><span class="quantity-cart-minus"></span></a> 
            <input type="text" name="pc[0-388599]" value="2" class="quantity" onclick="this.select()"> <a href="/cart?pc[0-388599]=3" class="quantity-cart-plus" onclick="return cart.quantity('0-388599',1)"><span class="quantity-cart-plus"></span></a> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cart_item_price_wrap">
        <a href="?del[0-388599]=1" class="cart_item_delete">
          <div class="wrapper_answer">
            <div class="answer">
              <p class="answer_text"><span>Вы уверены, что хотите удалить товар<br> из корзины?</span>
              </p>
              <div class="answer_buttons">
                <button class="del_from_cart answer_button_left" value="no">Нет</button>
                <button class="del_from_cart answer_button_right" value="yes" onclick="return cart._delete('0-388599')">Да</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="product-code">Код: id425913</div>
        <s style="visibility: hidden">&nbsp;</s>  <strong>
       <span class="span_word">Цена:</span>
       <span class="span_price">34&nbsp;157<span class="tRub">руб</span></span>
       </strong>
        <br>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return cart.toggle('0-388599')" title="Выбрать данный тип оплаты">
       Цена в кредит: от <span>1&nbsp;982<span class="tRub">руб</span>/мес</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!--cart_border-->
    <div id="promo-code">
      <div>
        <label title="Введите промо-код">
          <span>Введите промо-код</span>
          <input id="promo-code-value" maxlength="19" placeholder="Введите промо-код" type="text">
        </label>
        <button id="promo-code-apply" role="button" type="button">Применить</button>
      </div>
      <span id="promo-code-message"></span>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Да, так легче )) Но мой вариант тоже работает )

Comment: однако, это сработало )

Comment: Еще бы понять почему

Comment: @amijin По умолчанию тип кнопки *submit*. При нажатии *enter*, когда активно поле *input*, в форме идет обработка события на кнопке *submit* и всех ее родителях. Поэтому у Вас срабатывает событие на ссылке, являющейся родителем для кнопки. [Пример на jsffiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jsm7o8u2/)

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял, то вот так решается. Событие клика на другой элемент вызывается ещё при нажатии на клавишу. Мы пишем, что когда на ты в *input* нажимаешь на *enter*, то нечего не происходило, а когда ты отпускаешь *enter*, то вызывалась функция

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="text"]').keydown(function(){
    if(event.keyCode==13){
        return false;
    };
  });
  $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
    if(event.keyCode==13){
      alert($(this).attr('name'));  /* Это чтобы показать, что работает :) */
      return false;
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form c  lass="cart_form" method="post">
<div class="item_line_nomargin"></div>
<div class="cart_left_wrap">
  <div class="cart_border">   <div class="cart_item_photo"><a href="/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v">
     <img alt="LED Телевизор LG 43UF670V" src=""></a></div>
   <div class="cart_item_text">
    <div class="cart_item_name"><a href="/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v">LED Телевизор LG 43UF670V</a></div>
         <div class="item_avb availability_yes">В наличии</div>
        <div class="cart_item_quantity_wrap clearfix">
     <a href="cart/view?id=425913" onclick="return cart.view(425913,'/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v')" class="view-product">Посмотреть товар</a>
     <div class="cart_item_quantity">
      <a href="/cart?pc[0-388599]=1" class="quantity-cart-minus" onclick="return cart.quantity('0-388599',-1)"><span class="quantity-cart-minus"></span></a>      <input type="text" name="pc[0-388599]" value="2" class="quantity" onclick="this.select()">      <a href="/cart?pc[0-388599]=3" class="quantity-cart-plus" onclick="return cart.quantity('0-388599',1)"><span class="quantity-cart-plus"></span></a>     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="cart_item_price_wrap">
    <a href="?del[0-388599]=1" class="cart_item_delete">
     <div class="wrapper_answer">
      <div class="answer">
       <p class="answer_text"><span>Вы уверены, что хотите удалить товар<br> из корзины?</span></p>
       <div class="answer_buttons">
        <button class="del_from_cart answer_button_left" value="no">Нет</button>
        <button class="del_from_cart answer_button_right" value="yes" onclick="return cart._delete('0-388599')">Да</button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </a>
    <div class="product-code">Код: id425913</div>
    <s style="visibility: hidden">&nbsp;</s>              <strong>
       <span class="span_word">Цена:</span>
       <span class="span_price">34&nbsp;157<span class="tRub">руб</span></span>
       </strong><br>
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return cart.toggle('0-388599')" title="Выбрать данный тип оплаты">
       Цена в кредит: от <span>1&nbsp;982<span class="tRub">руб</span>/мес</span></a>
           </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   </div><!--cart_border-->   <div id="promo-code">
  <div>
   <label title="Введите промо-код">
    <span>Введите промо-код</span>
    <input id="promo-code-value" maxlength="19" placeholder="Введите промо-код" type="text">
   </label>
       <button id="promo-code-apply" role="button" type="submit">Применить</button>
      </div>
  <span id="promo-code-message"></span>
 </div>
     
 </div>lass="cart_form" method="post">
<div class="item_line_nomargin"></div>
<div class="cart_left_wrap">
  <div class="cart_border">   <div class="cart_item_photo"><a href="/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v">
     <img alt="LED Телевизор LG 43UF670V" src=""></a></div>
   <div class="cart_item_text">
    <div class="cart_item_name"><a href="/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v">LED Телевизор LG 43UF670V</a></div>
         <div class="item_avb availability_yes">В наличии</div>
        <div class="cart_item_quantity_wrap clearfix">
     <a href="cart/view?id=425913" onclick="return cart.view(425913,'/katalog/products/audio-video-tv-tehnika/televizory/led-televizory/led-televizor-lg-43uf670v')" class="view-product">Посмотреть товар</a>
     <div class="cart_item_quantity">
      <a href="/cart?pc[0-388599]=1" class="quantity-cart-minus" onclick="return cart.quantity('0-388599',-1)"><span class="quantity-cart-minus"></span></a>      <input type="text" name="pc[0-388599]" value="2" class="quantity" onclick="this.select()">      <a href="/cart?pc[0-388599]=3" class="quantity-cart-plus" onclick="return cart.quantity('0-388599',1)"><span class="quantity-cart-plus"></span></a>     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="cart_item_price_wrap">
    <a href="?del[0-388599]=1" class="cart_item_delete">
     <div class="wrapper_answer">
      <div class="answer">
       <p class="answer_text"><span>Вы уверены, что хотите удалить товар<br> из корзины?</span></p>
       <div class="answer_buttons">
        <button class="del_from_cart answer_button_left" value="no">Нет</button>
        <button class="del_from_cart answer_button_right" value="yes" onclick="return cart._delete('0-388599')">Да</button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </a>
    <div class="product-code">Код: id425913</div>
    <s style="visibility: hidden">&nbsp;</s>              <strong>
       <span class="span_word">Цена:</span>
       <span class="span_price">34&nbsp;157<span class="tRub">руб</span></span>
       </strong><br>
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return cart.toggle('0-388599')" title="Выбрать данный тип оплаты">
       Цена в кредит: от <span>1&nbsp;982<span class="tRub">руб</span>/мес</span></a>
           </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   </div><!--cart_border-->   <div id="promo-code">
  <div>
   <label title="Введите промо-код">
    <span>Введите промо-код</span>
    <input id="promo-code-value" maxlength="19" placeholder="Введите промо-код" type="text">
   </label>
       <button id="promo-code-apply" role="button" type="submit">Применить</button>
      </div>
  <span id="promo-code-message"></span>
 </div>
     
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Да , но это костыль. И Всё таки причина такого поведения пока неясна. Ведь по идее клик должен генерироваться только на unput type submit , а не как в моем случае, на какой-то сторонний элемент

Comment: @amijin, если не указан тип кнопки, то оно будет принимать любую кнопку как submit

Comment: Т.е. получается, что даже если в форме будет input type submit, но при этом если в форме есть button без type, то сработает событие click на первом попавшемся в DOM дереве button без type ?

Comment: @amijin, я точно не знаю, не разбирался в этом. Но на парактике - да